how to efficiently find prefabs that are using a script in Unity?
In Unity, is there an efficient way to find all prefabs that are using a specific script component? One easy but inefficient way is to iterate e.g in Bash, all the .prefab files in the project, and check if the .prefab file contains the guid of the script. but this is slow
How to efficiently find prefabs that are using a specific script component?

The easiest would be to use the context menu (right click on the file) and use the option Find references in project which gives you a nice small menu that lists the scenes, prefabs and hierarchy where you use that script.
 
